# Getting InvalidProgramException on MSTest using vstest.console.exe

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, vstest, invalidprogramexception

[image: InvalidProgramException]

I'm getting this weird InvalidProgramException  when trying to call a static method from a static class that's in an external assembly.

I've already tried bringing the routine within the same assembly, but the result is the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does TestHelper.Login do?

Comment: It's a simpified RestSharp call, making the login through a WebRequest, not much stuff into it

Comment: This is possibly related to this unanswered question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768123/visual-studio-2015-invalidprogramexception-in-unit-test-with-fakes