# InvalidProgramException with shims in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-fakes, invalidprogramexception

An almost similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768123/visual-studio-2015-invalidprogramexception-in-unit-test-with-fakes) has already been asked a while ago but not answered yet. And since my setup is a little different, I start a new try:

I demonstrate a shortened version of my code, but even this short version produces the error.

I have a method that returns an instance of a `System.Printing.LocalPrintServer`:

```
public class PrintServerProvider
{
    public LocalPrintServer Provide()
    {
        return new LocalPrintServer(new string[0], PrintSystemDesiredAccess.EnumerateServer);
    }
}
```

For this method I implemented a unit test using shims:

```
[TestClass]
public class PrintServerProviderTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Provide_Success()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            bool constructorCalled = false;
            ShimLocalPrintServer.ConstructorStringArrayPrintSystemDesiredAccess = (instance, props, access) =>
            {
                constructorCalled = true;
            };

            PrintServerProvider provider = new PrintServerProvider();
            LocalPrintServer server = provider.Provide();
            Assert.IsNotNull(server);
            Assert.IsTrue(constructorCalled);
        }
    }
}
```

In Visual Studio **2013** this test **works fine**.
But in Visual Studio **2015 (Update 1)**, when the tested method calls `new LocalPrintServer(...)` an

> InvalidProgramException
>      at System.Printing.LocalPrintServer..ctor(String[] propertiesFilter, PrintSystemDesiredAccess desiredAccess)
>      at DemoProject.PrintServerProvider.Provide() in C:\Projects\DemoProject\Program.cs:Line 10.
>   ...

is raised.
(The normal productive call works fine. The exception is only raised when running the test method)

The referenced assemblies are:

- System.Printing (v4.0.30319) from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Printing.dll
- System.Printing.4.0.0.0.Fakes
- Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes (v2.0.50727) from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.dll

**System.Printing.Fakes**

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
<Assembly Name="System.Printing" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Clear/>
  </StubGeneration>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add FullName="System.Printing.LocalPrintServer!"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

Both projects (productive and test) use .NET Framework 4.5.

I tried resetting the framework as well as the references. I tried different versions of the referenced assemblies. And I tried 64bit and 32bit in all variations.

In the real code, I use shims of other classes too. `LocalPrintServer` is the only class where the exception occurs.

**Can anybody explain what causes this `InvalidProgramException` and how to solve it?**

I set a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768123/visual-studio-2015-invalidprogramexception-in-unit-test-with-fakes/35231206?noredirect=1#comment58177332_35231206), which will probably be solved by the same answer. So feel free to post there too if you think your answer is bounty-worth.

Comment: Are you signing/strongnaming assemblies?

Comment: @Ben `System.Printing` is strong named as it is part of the framework. My own assemblies are not strong named (which is not a problem for Visual Studio 2013)

Comment: The original question is much more impressive, simply removing an assembly that doesn't get used and never gets loaded fixes the problem.  Excessively bizarre.  I can also make it fail on VS2013 and the target framework does not matter.  Somebody needs to take this to Microsoft, start with connect.microsoft.com